# How to display button (Tkinter) red or green when we got 0 or 1 data?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have project for read and show data from text file.

```
import os
import io

work_dir = "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\labels"

for index in range(191, 221):
    name = "CushionOK_{index}.txt".format(index=index)
    path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        content = fd.read(1)
int(content)

if int(content) == 1:
  print("OK")
else:
  print("NG")
```

From above code is show only OK or NG but I'd like to show button (Tkinter) red or green too.

For red(NG)

```
import tkinter as tk

root2 = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root2,text='NG',font=('Helvetica bold',150), bg = "red").place(
            x=250, y= 250, w= 350, h= 350, anchor='center')

tk.Button(root2,text='Sign in', bg = "grey").place(x=250, y= 450,w= 60, h= 30,
                                                   anchor='center')

root2.geometry("500x500")
root2.mainloop()
```

For Red(NG) button will push sign in button for apply private code (Ex.1234) to show other folder.

and Green button(OK).

```
import tkinter as tk

root1 = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root1,text='OK',font=('Helvetica bold',150), bg = "green").place(
            x=250, y= 250, w= 350, h= 350, anchor='center')

tk.Button(root1,text='Confirm', bg = "grey").place(
            x=250, y= 450,w= 60, h= 30, anchor='center')

root1.geometry("500x500")
root1.mainloop()
```

For Green button will push confirm button for close it.

I'd like to show button (Tkinter) red or green for represent 0 (red button) or 1 (green button).
Now I can create separate code but I'd like to add all code together.

Comment: Did you run into a problem while adding all the code together? If yes, you can explain what problem you faced and we can help you rectify it. Currently, the question is too generic and it is not exactly clear what solution you expect.

Comment: What the point of using for loop in your first code block? Finally the value of `content` is from the last file read in the for loop, so the for loop is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

I put all the widgets in one script as you asked for. As for me, it will work w/out using `work_dir`. But you can do by yourself.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import io


root = tk.Tk()

def confirm():
    work_dir = "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\labels"

    for index in range(191, 221):
        name = "CushionOK_{index}.txt".format(index=index)
        path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
        with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
            content = fd.read(1)
    int(content)
            
def quit():
    root.destroy()
        
 

if int(content) == 1:
    tk.Button(root,text='OK',
              font=('Helvetica bold',150),
              bg = "green").place(x=250, y= 250, w= 350, h= 350, anchor='center')

    tk.Button(root,text='Confirm',
              command=confirm,
              bg = "grey").place(x=250, y= 450,w= 60, h= 30, anchor='center')
else:
     tk.Button(root,text='NG',
               font=('Helvetica bold',150),
               bg = "red").place(x=250, y= 250, w= 350, h= 350, anchor='center')

     tk.Button(root,text='Sign in',
               command=quit,
               bg = "grey").place(x=250, y= 450,w= 60, h= 30, anchor='center')
 

root.geometry("500x500")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: W/out using work_dir. I used variable content= 0 for red or content= 1 for green

Comment: The line `int(content)` will raise exception because `content` is not defined.

Comment: @acw1668.  I don't know about filename.CushionOK_{index}.txt. So I cannot test it. I can only do w/out filename. It is up to Kukkik.

Comment: The issue is not what the value of `content` is or where the value comes from. It is an issue when you use `content`.  Same issue (`content` is undefined) on the line `if int(content) == 1:`.